# Text Sizes in multline Environment

Tags: equations, fontsize, size, multline

I'm having issues getting a size change for the text in the entirety of a `multline` environment. I tried `\mbox` but that screws up the couple of sum symbols I have in there by putting their sub-and-superscripts after the symbol instead of above and below it.

More weirdly, it does work for single characters if I'm doing `\Big(...\Big)`. I'd just really rather not put in a `\scriptsize` for every single character if I can avoid it. Here's an example demonstrating my issue: the `\scriptsize` command works for equations but not for multline.

```
\begin{equation}
    \scriptsize{5x=3y}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
   \scriptsize{5x=3y}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Scriptsize is a text command and should not be used in math as is warned in the log.

Answer (score 1):

I only answer for what I have understood. :-) `LaTeX` knows several font size modifier-commands (from biggest to smallest): `\scriptsize` it is only in the textual mode (or text-mode). For math-mode the command is `\scriptstyle`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \scriptstyle{5x=3y}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
   \scriptstyle{5x=3y}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I feel the fool. Thanks for the help!